# Casting generic class types to non-generic or calling methods of their instances?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to do one of the following:

```
Dummy d = (Class<Dummy>)super.getEntity();  // incompatible Types - cannot cast
Dummy d = (Dummy)super.getEntity();  // incompatible Types - cannot cast
d.foo();
```

or

```
Class<Dummy> d = (Class<Dummy>)super.getEntity(); // works
d.foo(); // method cannot be found
```

Dummy d is defined in an abstract superclass as follows:

```
Class<T> dummy;
public Class<T> getEntity() { return dummy; }
```

Is there any way to call a method (foo) in an object of Generic class type? The point is that the superclass should NOT care about the type of the object, so that functionality can vary by the extending classes.

Comment: Is your "getEntity()" method on the superclass supposed to return an object of type <T> or Class<T>?  It seems like your member should be defined as "T dummy" instead of "Class<T> dummy" and getEntity() should return an instance of T.

Answer (score 2):

Your `getEntity()` method returns a *class token*, not an instance of that class, so you can't call `foo()` on it, only the methods defined in the interface of [`java.lang.Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). You need to *instantiate* that class first (by calling [`newInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) - it requires that the class has a public default constructor), then you have a class object, upon which you may call `foo()`:

```
Class<Dummy> clazz = super.getEntity();
try {
  Dummy d = clazz.newInstance();
  d.foo();
} catch (...) {
}
```

Notes:

- since `getEntity()` is generic, it will return the proper class type, thus the cast to `Class<Dummy>` is not needed,
- `Class.newInstance()` may throw various exceptions, which you must handle, hence the try-catch block. This is one of the reasons reflection is not a preferred way of solving such issues,
- since in the derived class you know the exact type parameter used in the base class, this code is unnecessarily verbose and rather contrived.

Alternatively, you may prefer returning `T` from `getEntity()` instead of `Class<T>` - this way you can call `foo()` directly on the object returned. Note that since you can't instantiate generic types directly, you need to either pass an instance of the class to the superclass (e.g. as a constructor parameter, or through an overridden virtual method), or create it using reflection as described above.

Here is how to do it using a constructor parameter:

```
public abstract class ABC<T> {
  private T dummy;
  public ABC(T dummy) { this.dummy = dummy; }
  ...
  public T getEntity() { return dummy; }

}

public class DEF extends ABC<Dummy> {
  public DEF() {
    super(new Dummy(); }
  }
  public void doSomething() {
    Dummy dummy = getEntity();
    dummy.foo();
  }
}
```

Comment: dummy is instantiated in the constructor, 
public abstract ABC<T> {

Comment: dummy is instantiated in the constructor, 
public abstract ABC<T> { public ABC(Class<T> dummy) { this.dummy = dummy; } ... }  If dummy is not an instance, how can I get a reference to its instance?